# Is it natural to say "I happened to bite on a grit while eating rice"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

In some farmers grows rice and grind rice grains into rice. People say that rice is healthier than rice you buy in the supermarket.

However, there is a downside. That is the farmers' technology is not as good as rice producing factories and the rice of the farmers often contain tiny bits of stone which are as small as a rice and not easy to see.
When you eat this rice, you might bite on them, which cause a terrible yucky feeling.

Rice producing factories have technology to get rid of these tiny bits of stone.

Do you say "**these tiny bits of stone**" "**grits**"?

So, before cooking the rice, the farmers often put the rice into a basket with tiny hole or into a washing bowl, then they wash the rice in water and move the rice gently to the left or right to look for the grits.

Do you say "**I pan the rice for grits before cooking**" or "**I sift out the grits from the rice**" (note: the rice will not go through the tiny holes of the baskets, it just stay in there)?

See this picture

[image]

Source: https://gaogiahung.com/vo-gao-dung-cach-de-khong-bi-mat-chat-dinh-duong/

also, Is it natural to say "**I happened to bite on a grit while eating rice**"?

Comment: No, for this meaning "grit" is usually noncount; I'd say "I happened to bite on a bit of grit." (Which leads to the awkwardly toungue-twister-like "I bit a bit of grit in my grits...")

Comment: Note, "grit" is typically very small, like glitter. It's reasonable for particles the size of grains of rice, but if they get much bigger they might just be called pebbles (e.g. when picking them out of beans).

Comment: Are you confusing gritty stones with grits (hominy corn) that are eaten?

Comment: You don't 'grind rice grains into rice'. If you grind the individual grains you get _ground rice_ or _rice flour_.

Answer (score 3):

In this sense "grit" is usually considered uncountable.  So:

> I wash the rice to get rid of grit.

> I happened to bite on a piece of grit while eating rice.

As a countable (but plural) word "grits" are a type of porridge, made with roughly ground corn with a gritty texture that are eaten particularly in the south of the USA.  (Yet another example of language not being logical)

Answer (score 0):

**Stones** seems the usual term for small bits of rock found in foods such as cereals and pulses.

[Times of India](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/food-news/these-easy-tips-can-help-remove-impurities-from-rice/photostory/104395321.cms?from=mdr) talks about removing "stones" from rice, and the [FAO](https://www.fao.org/pulses-2016/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-lentils/en/) tells you to remove stones from lentils (another staple commonly containing small pieces of rock). There are also a lot of results on Reddit, Quora, etc.

There is a book about a westerner in Iran called *Pebbles in the Rice* by Lisa Radcliffe but that seems self-consciously quirky (a pebble is a specific type of stone, usually smooth and
larger than grit/rice grains).

So "stones" is fine.

Comment: Let's not mention 'gravel'; that would only confuse things!